# Can someone tell me why my carousel has caused all my text elements to move?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why all my text elements including my footer have moved when I added a carousel to the code, can someone tell me how to align them back to the left?

https://codepen.io/alex-burger/pen/LrxOZW

```
    <div class="footer"> 
    <p style="font-size: 1.4vw;"> &copy; Alex Burger. All rights 
    reserved<br>Further information can be requested through email.</p>
    </div>

   .footer{
   position:relative;
   display: block;
   bottom:0!important; 
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;

   }
```

Comment: the footer is in a left side can you explain what your issuse or attach some pic

Comment: I want it to be fully to the left, it is currently partially moved to the right inline with the carousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your example on codepen, the only CSS property moving your contents away from the left side of the viewport is the width of `.contentwrapper`.

So Removing the `width: 90vw;` there would push all your contents back to the left.

Comment: I want the carousel within the .contentwrapper to be where it is but all the other content to be fully to the left. how might this be achieved?

Comment: Thats possible. You could simply do that, by removing the "width: 90vw;" from .contentwrapper. Then add "width: 90vw;" and "margin: 0 auto;" to the carousel (.main-carousel).